# Google Spreadsheet to Google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

1. When changing from Google Sheet to Form
2. The problem goes in, but the question is marked as Object.

```
function getDataFromGoogleSheets() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('test');
  const [header, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const choices = {};

  header.forEach(function(title, index) {
    choices[title] = data.map(row => row[index]).filter(e => e !== '');
  });

  return choices;
}

function myFunction() {

  const choices = getDataFromGoogleSheets();

  var form = FormApp.create('New Form');

  Logger.log(choices)

  for (var i in choices){
    form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
      .setTitle(choices) // [object Object] ???
      .setChoiceValues(choices[i]) // Okay
      .showOtherOption(true);
      Logger.log(choices[i]);
}
}
```

I want to get a "P-1~4" value, but I can't, so I post a question.

Comment: From your question, I proposed an answer with my guess. Please confirm it. If my guess was not correct, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By this, I would like to modify my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About `I want to get a "P-1~4" value`, unfortunately, I couldn't find the origin of your expected value in your question. So, this is just my guess. In your situation, when the header titles are the title of each question, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your `myFunction()` was modified.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const choices = getDataFromGoogleSheets();
  var form = FormApp.create('New Form');
  Logger.log(choices)
  for (var i in choices) {
    form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
      .setTitle(i) // <--- Modified
      .setChoiceValues(choices[i])
      .showOtherOption(true);
    Logger.log(choices[i]);
  }
}
```

- I guessed that the reason for your current issue is due to that `choices` is directly used. It seems that `choices` is a JSON object.